# How to make HTML Form to open a new page everytime we submit new value

Tags: html, forms

I have a form which on submit refer to a PHP page, currently i am using the following code.

```
<form action="load.php" method="post" target="_blank" class="form">
```

the problem is, if i click submit on new values it will reload the same new page, How can i make it open a completely new windows everytime i submit the form.

Comment: I got it Work using.

     <form action="load.php" method="post" target="_blank"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">

and 

     <input type="submit"  onClick=**"window.open"** value="Executar"  id="but"/></p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work using:

```
<form action="load.php" method="post" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
```

and

```
<input type="submit" onClick="window.open" value="Executar" id="but"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **load.php** at the end you could do this

```
<?php 
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
window.open("new url here"); 
</script>'; 
?>
```